# How to add definition of WithEvents variable which require Handles clause

Tags: vb.net, events

In order to make my program more elegant and better organized in concrete case I would like to change `DataGridView1variable` with referenced variable on top of my `Form1` class

```
Private aDgv As DataGridView
```

And assign value in `Form1_Load`

```
aDgv = DataGridView1
```

After that I can use `aDgv` variable across that `Form`.
Except in such case:

```
Private Sub aDgv_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles aDgv.KeyDown
aDgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
'etc...
End Sub
```

Where I get an error:

> Handles clause requires a `WithEvents` variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
>   And `aDgv` variable after `Handles` clause is blue underlined.

What to do to get rid of error and get `Handles aDgv.SomeEvent` to work?
Of course, with referenced `aDgv` instead of original control name `DataGridView1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The minimal answer is to add `WithEvents` to `aDgv`:

```
Private WithEvents aDgv As DataGridView
```

Comment: Minimal. But rocks! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Mark Hurd also works for me. But here's a detailed way on how to do that for beginners like I am.

- Highlight the variable in your code that has a blue underline
- Press <kbd>F12</kbd>
- It will take you to the `designer.vb`
- You will then immediately see the variable that was highlighted earlier
- Now just put `WithEvents` word after the `Friend` word
- Done